# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on AWS EMR/Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark project on AWS/EMR which includes the following dependency:

```
"com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-analyticsreporting" % "v4-rev20210106-1.31.0"
"com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.31.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "com.google.guava"))
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "29.0-jre"
```

However at runtime I get the error:

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J
    at com.google.api.client.http.ConsumingInputStream.close(ConsumingInputStream.java:40)
....
```

This is the assembly definition:

```
lazy val assemblySettings = nocomma {
  assembly / target := (baseDirectory in ThisBuild).value / "target" / "jars"
  assembly / assemblyJarName := s"${name.value}.jar"
  assembly / test := {}
  assembly / assemblyOption := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
  assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
    case PathList("log4j.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("/org/apache/log4j", _@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("META-INF", _@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x if Assembly.isConfigFile(x) => MergeStrategy.concat
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

After I have unzipped the file, I can see the `.class` files at the right places. Any idea?

Comment: Did you include those dependencies in the JAR running in EMR?

Comment: yes and built as assembly

Comment: I can actually see the "class" files in the unzipped final jar.

Comment: That is weird, does it work if you run in your local?

Comment: yes locally (IntelliJ) works.

Comment: This is one of the typical situations where multiple incompatible versions of Guava are present in the classpath. And since you said the code works well in your IDE, the problem comes from one of the Hadoop libraries included in the EMR environment. Having said that, I am afraid there is no simple solution to your problem. The easiest to try first is to set both `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` and `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, tried but unfortunately didn'work